# Storing web content in cache in c# .NET windows application

Tags: c#, .net

I am developing a windows application in c# in which I am showing a web page using web browser  control, and I want to store the content of the web page in a cache. How can i do?

Answer (score 2):

If you simply store the DocumentText property of the control, that will only enable you to cache the HTML content. Objects such as Images and stylesheets won't be cached.

If you want to also cache images and stylesheets then, you will need to parse the contents of the DocumentText property and retrieve objects such as images and stylesheets from the web server they are stored on and keep a local copy, then update the links in the DocumentText property to point to the local versions.

Use the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(VS.80).aspx) class to download a copy of an object on a remote web server.

Comment: actually iam just showing a web page which contain rss feed and i want a kind of notification for new feed . for this i want to store rss feed in cache  so that i can compare it with previous one . will only  using document text property will work.

Comment: Yes, that should work fine. Whilst RSS feeds can contain images, if you don't care about the image changing, then you only need to store the DocumentText property.